# Permanent USB Power Off Mains

Tags: electrical, power, uk

I'm having my house (in the UK) rewired and want to install some PIR sensors ([link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Aeotec-DSB05-ZWEU-Z-Wave-Multisensor-White/dp/B00QFEYNJE/)) in a few rooms. Instead of using batteries there's an option to have them permanently powered via USB cable. Is there a device (transformer?) I can have my electrician install to step the mains power down and provide a permanent USB supply?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Maybe something like [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/110-240V-Switching-Supply-Converter-S-A10-05/dp/B008ODQ5V8) is what I'm after? A 240V to 5V Switching Power Converter. Unfortunately there's not much info on it...

EDIT2:
Thanks for the help I've found what I was after: [USB Euro Module Charger](http://ccsukltd.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&path=13450_13403&product_id=147646)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transformer, rectifier, regulator - aka, a USB power supply.

There are, of course, the small switching supplies that plug in, as seen as phone, ipad, ipod (or any other USB device) chargers.

I know that there are power outlets (ac) with built-in USB outlets available for the USA system - depending on the speed and conservatism of the UK electric regulators, that sort of thing will either exist, or be coming at some point. Looks like it's a done deal:

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution in my mind. Great find.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have a few of these going in to the house aswell! As the power cable will be hidden (comes out of the ceiling) I'm looking for something that steps down the power like this socket does but is more compact and dedicated solely to providing the USB power. I'm sure something must exist, I just can't seem to find it!

Comment: try "UK wallplate USB Charger" image search, and look for the ones without AC receptacles.

Comment: Ah, Thanks for the tip, it lead me to find [this](http://ccsukltd.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&path=13450_13403&product_id=147646)  which is exactly what I'm after!

Comment: i just wanted to chime in quick and mention that with the new USB type C standard, these style outlets might become outdated relatively soon.

Comment: Do the switches control the USB ports as well as the mains? I like the form factor of this but would not be keen on having constant sources of vampire power use built into my walls.

Comment: It looks like even amazon has power supplies that could be hardwired if you're looking for more of a custom application [LINK](http://www.amazon.com/MicroMall-Universal-Regulated-Switching-Supply/dp/B00HF3G7NO)

Comment: @DLeh the shape of the plugs themselves isn't likely to be the issue, you can always use A-C cables afterall.  I'd be more concerned about the addition of 5A@ 5V/12V/20V modes.  While the latter is unlikely to end up in a combination wall outlet (100W is a largish laptop charger), near future phones/tablets are probably going to want more than the 1-2A @ 5V provided by current products.